# Оптимизация. Количество возможных решений Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, оптимизация

Имеется задание, найти количество решений, нужно оптимизировать , чтобы этот код выполнялся используя не 4 цикла , а 3 (но лучше 2 цикла). Нужно понизить сложность кода.

Формула:

```
xa^2 + yb^2 = xc^2 + yd^2
```

```
n , x , y = map(int,input().split())

counter = 0
for a in range(n+1):
    for b in range(n+1):
        for c in range(n+1):
            for d in range(n+1):
                if (x*(a**2))+(y*(b**2)) == (x*(c**2)) +(y*(d**2)):
                    counter += 1
print(counter)
```

Comment: а слабо было формулу привести в вопросе, а не через кривой код

Comment: x*a^2 + y*b^2 = x*c^2 + y*d^2 в чём проблема?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

У @Danis получилось очень хорошее и очень быстрое решение, но его можно сделать еще быстрее (ориентировочно где-то в 5-10 раз - проверял на `n = 200, x = 10, y = 20`):

```
list_ = [x * a * a + y * b * b
          for a in range(n + 1)
          for b in range(n + 1)]

list_.sort()
list_.append(list_[-1] + 1)

counter = 0
local = 1
for i in range(1, len(list_)):
    if list_[i - 1] == list_[i]:
        local += 1
    else:
        counter += local**2
        local = 1

print(counter)
```

Вот еще более быстрый (где-то на 5%) вариант:

```
list_ = [x * a * a + y * b * b
          for a in range(n + 1)
          for b in range(n + 1)]

list_.sort()
list_.append(list_[-1] + 1)

counter = 0
pos = 0
for i in range(1, len(list_)):
    if list_[i - 1] != list_[i]:
        counter += (i - pos)**2
        pos = i

print(counter)
```

Проверял на `x = 10, y = 20, n = 2000`, время выполнения 1,92сек

Вот этот код работает еще на 5% быстрее:

```
list_ = [x * a * a + y * b * b
          for a in range(n + 1)
          for b in range(n + 1)]

list_.sort()
list_.append(list_[-1] + 1)

counter = 0
pos = 0
value = list_[0]
for i in range(1, len(list_)):
    if list_[i] != value:
        counter += (i - pos)**2
        pos = i
        value = list_[i]

print(counter)
```

Вот этот код работает еще на 18% быстрее:

```
list_ = []

for a in range(n + 1):
    value = x * a * a
    for b in range(n + 1):
        list_.append(value + y * b * b)

list_.sort()
list_.append(list_[-1] + 1)

counter = 0
pos = 0
value = list_[0]

for i in range(1, len(list_)):
    if list_[i] != value:
        counter += (i - pos)**2
        pos = i
        value = list_[i]

print(counter)
```

Вот этот код работает еще на 13% быстрее:

```
abx = []
aby = []

for i in range(n + 1):
    abx.append(x * i * i)
    aby.append(y * i * i)

list_ = []

for a in abx:
    for b in aby:
        list_.append(a + b)

list_.sort()
list_.append(list_[-1] + 1)

counter = 0
pos = 0
value = list_[0]

for i in range(1, len(list_)):
    if list_[i] != value:
        counter += (i - pos)**2
        pos = i
        value = list_[i]

print(counter)
```

Вот этот код работает ещё на 22% быстрее (спасибо @Danis за идею уйти от степеней):

```
abx = []
aby = []

for i in range(n + 1):
    abx.append(x * i * i)
    aby.append(y * i * i)

list_ = []

for a in abx:
    for b in aby:
        list_.append(a + b)

list_.sort()
list_.append(list_[-1] + 1)

counter = 0
pos = 0
value = list_[0]

for i in range(1, len(list_)):
    if list_[i] != value:
        counter += (i - pos) * (i - pos)
        pos = i
        value = list_[i]

print(counter)
```

Вот этот код работает еще на 9% быстрее:

```
abx = []
aby = []

for i in range(n + 1):
    abx.append(x * i * i)
    aby.append(y * i * i)

list_ = [a + b for a in abx for b in aby]

list_.sort()
list_.append(list_[-1] + 1)

counter = 0
pos = 0
value = list_[0]

for i in range(1, len(list_)):
    if list_[i] != value:
        counter += (i - pos) * (i - pos)
        pos = i
        value = list_[i]

print(counter)
```

Comment: протестируйте ваш и мой код на этих данных `n = 1000, x = 0, y = 0`

Comment: @Danis, на `1000, 0, 0` ваш код быстрее в 1.4 раза - `0.152сек` против `0.208сек`, на `100, 10, 10` мой код быстрее в 110 раз (!) - `0.00365 сек` против `0.4 сек`, при `2000, 10, 20` мой код дает `1.92 сек`, ваш работал несколько минут и я его вырубил

Comment: @Danis, последняя версия кода стала обгонять ваш на 45-50% для `1000, 0, 0` - `0.15сек` против `0.10сек`, а для `100, 10, 10` в 158 раз, однако если в ваш код поставить мой код формирования `list_`, то для `1000, 0, 0` ваш код работает на 28% быстрее - `0.078сек` против `0.10сек`, правда для `100, 10, 10` все равно в 156 раз медленнее

Answer (score 5):

```
list_ = [x * a * a + y * b * b
          for a in range(n + 1)
          for b in range(n + 1)]


counter = 0
for a in set(list_):
    counter += list_.count(a) ** 2
print(counter)
```

Правую и левую часть можно вычислять заранее

```
left  = [x * i * i for i in range(n + 1)]
right = [y * i * i for i in range(n + 1)]
list_ = [a + b
         for a in left
         for b in right]

counter = 0
for a in set(list_):
    counter += list_.count(a) ** 2
print(counter)
```

`list.count` очень не эффективен, быстрее будет пройтись по всему списку и добавлять значения в словарь

```
left  = [x * i * i for i in range(n + 1)]
right = [y * i * i for i in range(n + 1)]
list_ = [a + b
         for a in left
         for b in right]

dict_ = {el: 0 for el in set(list_)}

for el in dict_:
    dict_[el] += 1
   
print(sum(el * el for el in dict_.values()))
```

Comment: красивое решение

Comment: Посмотрите мой ответ - я чуть подкрутил ваш алгоритм :) - отказался от `set` и `count`

Comment: Очень красивое решение. Я только слегка изменил ваш заключительный подсчет в [моем ответе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1213428/233990).

Answer (score 2):

вариант 1 (быстрее исходного):

```
counter = 0

arr = []
for a in range(n + 1):
    for b in range(n + 1):
        arr.append(a**2 - b**2)

for value1 in arr:
    for value2 in arr:
        if x * value1 == y * value2:
            counter += 1

print(counter)
```

вариант 2 (еще быстрее):

```
counter = 0

arr = []
for a in range(n + 1):
    for b in range(n + 1):
        arr.append(a**2 - b**2)

for value1 in arr:
    value2 = x * value1 // y
    counter += arr.count(value2)

print(counter)
```

вариант 3 (возможно чуть медленнее, чем вариант 2):

```
arr = [(a**2 - b**2) for a in range(n + 1) for b in range(n + 1)]

counter = sum(arr.count(x * value // y) for value in arr)

print(counter)
```

Comment: Не подходит, слишком медленно работает.

Comment: Все 3 варианта медленно работают? А можно все таки тогда задачу текстом

Answer (score 2):

Оптимизированный вариант вашей программы — около 5 раз быстрее:

```
n, x, y = map(int, input().split())

counter = 0
for a in range(n+1):
    a = x * a * a
    for b in range(n+1):
        b = y * b * b
        left = a + b
        for c in range(n+1):
            c = x * c * c
            for d in range(n+1):
                d = y * d * d
                if left == c + d:
                    counter += 1
print(counter)
```

---

*Объяснение:*

Выражения `x*a^2`, `y*b^2` (и их сумма), `x*c^2`, `y*d^2` вычисляются только один раз.

Comment: проверил своим для `n = 100, x = 5, y = 5`, мой в 6095 раз быстрее :))))

Comment: @Zhihar, я тоже проверил, тоже для `n = 100, x = 5, y = 5`. Мой в 12 раз быстрее. Проверите еще один раз - ваш результат не возможный, т. к. *мой вариант делает те же самые инструкции, что ваш, но в очень меньшем количестве.*

Comment: `counter = 34449`, ваш код работает `11.22сек`, последняя версия моего `0.002сек`, использую PyCharm

Comment: @Zhihar, что это «последняя версия моего»?

Comment: В посте же есть - я там несколько итераций приводил: abx = []
aby = []

for i in range(n + 1):
    abx.append(x * i * i)
    aby.append(y * i * i)

list_ = [a + b for a in abx for b in aby]

list_.sort()
list_.append(list_[-1] + 1)

counter = 0
pos = 0
value = list_[0]

for i in range(1, len(list_)):
    if list_[i] != value:
        counter += (i - pos) * (i - pos)
        pos = i
        value = list_[i]

print(counter)

Comment: @Zhihar, o, я думал, что вы человек, который задал вопрос, и сравнивает его код с моим. Моя ошибка. Значит, вы сравниваете ваш код с моим. В порядке, ваш код гораздо быстрее моего.

Answer (score 2):

Вы также можете использовать библиотеку numba, которая использует just in time компилятор(дает ускорение примерно в 40 раз), в ней можно отключать GIL и использовать мультипоточность, также есть поддержка cuda.
Использование очень простое, накидываем декоратор njit на функцию и добавляем параметры какие захотим и prange есть для распаралеливания.

```
from numba import njit

@njit(nogil=True,parallel=True)   
def foo():
    pass
```

Comment: Нельзя использовать библиотеки

Answer (score 1):

Слегка улучшен конец [красивого решения](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1211661/233990) [Danis](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/400096/danis)-а —  применением класса `Counter`:

```
from collections import Counter

n, x, y = map(int, input().split())

list_ = [x * a * a + y * b * b
          for a in range(n + 1)
          for b in range(n + 1)]

counter = sum(val * val for val in Counter(list_).values())
print(counter)
```

Comment: можно левую и правую часть вычесть заранее ```left   = [x * i * i for i in range(n + 1)]
right = [y * i * i for i in range(n + 1)]

list_ = [a + b
            for a in left
            for b in right]```

Comment: @Danis, да, вы тем улучшили ваше собственное решение. :-)