# Найти количество решений уравнения python

Tags: python, python-3.x

[image: Условие задачи]

Я решил эту задачу но она слишком долго проходить компиляцию и поэтому задачу не засчитывает, можете помочь ускорить её?

```
n, x, y = map(int, input().split())
solutions = 0
for range1 in range(n+1):
    for range2 in range(n+1):
        for range3 in range(n+1):
            for range4 in range(n+1):
                if x*range1**2+y*range2**2-x*range3**2-y*range4**2 == 0:
                    solutions += 1
                else:
                    solutions += 0
print(solutions)
```

Comment: [С этой задачей](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1235545/) ещё не закончили

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Оптимизация. Количество возможных решений Python](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1211613/%d0%9e%d0%bf%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%9a%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%be-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85-%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%88%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b9-python)

Comment: @MBo, я уже разобрался с той задачей

Comment: @Derzh возможно поделитесь своими знаниями?

Comment: @5c0rp, конечно с радостью, куда код написать?

Comment: @Derzh можете дополнить свой вопрос

Comment: В  ответе на свой вопрос